# How to debug a blob triggered azure function on VScode without it re-running on all the existing blobs

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, triggers, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

**Note**: In the question below, I am not deploying the function, I just want to debug the function and see some values to confirm my code.

I have an azure function that I test locally on VScode (azure extension). This function is blob triggered i.e. triggered an an image is uplaoded to ac ertain blob container (say `c`). I have also linked my blob storage my vscode. The storage container `c` has a lot of images already (200+). When I change anything  in my azure function, I want to debug it using a single new image upload. But as soon as I hit debug, it shows a lot of blobs triggered (please see snapshot). Sometimes I have to wait a long time as it seems to trigger all the blobs but I want that function is only triggered by the new upload I do.

Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Edit:

My blob trigger/azure function is way too long so I will just post on how it triggers

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream, doc: func.Out[func.Document]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

    blob_val = myblob.read()
    .
    .
    .
```

and `host.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this is insufficient. In short, my function is triggered when it sees a new image (with a certain suffix), does some processing on the image and uploads the computed metadata somewhere.

[image]

Comment: could you please provide your `blob trigger function` code and `host.json` code

Comment: can't you just use the local blob emulator? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator

Comment: I don't want to use blob emulator because I have way too many files to keep track of between emulator and the real storage, unfortunately.