# When I run an azure function locally (which uploads a data to cosmos), does it replace the existing cosmos data?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb

**Note**: In the question below, I have not yet deployed the function.

I have an azure function that I test locally on VScode (azure extension). This function is blob triggered i.e. triggered when an image is uploaded to a certain blob container (say `c`) and later uploads a certain metadata (`dict`) on cosmos. I have also linked my blob storage my vscode. The storage container `c` has a lot of images already (200+). When I run my azure function locally (on VScode), it seems to be running the function on all existing images again.
It is an issue I have asked elsewhere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71823227/how-to-debug-a-blob-triggered-azure-function-on-vscode-without-it-re-running-on) (picture attached).

[image]

**But I have a second question**. If this function is running on all triggers on VSCode (not deployed yet), is it replacing/re-writing all my data on cosmos (my azure function uploads some data to cosmos in the end)

Edit:

My blob trigger/azure function is way too long so I will just post on how it triggers

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream, doc: func.Out[func.Document]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

    blob_val = myblob.read()
    .
    .
    .
```

and `host.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant code, output, errors, etc. This also applies to details around what you're writing to Cosmos DB, how you're getting your connection string setting, etc. It's unclear what, specifically, you're asking (it's very high level). Also, it's really important to only include properly-formatted text, not images of text. Please read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for more details.

Comment: I have added the code. I am sort of new to azure functions so I dont know what details can I best provide to make the question more clearer. As for the photo, the details in the terminal come at a very fast speed so I quickly took photo of it to paste here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of where the Function is running (your local machine, Azure, any other [supported hosting options](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale)), if your configuration has the Cosmos DB Connection String of a real Cosmos DB account, then the Function will perform the update on that account.

Simply the answer to your question is: The update will be performed on the account your Connection String points to regardless of where the Function is running.

One alternative, if you want to do local testing, is to use the [Cosmos DB Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) and have your local configuration Connection String use the Emulator's Connection String, so your local testing won't affect any real account.

And you can have that setting overwritten when running on Azure by adding that setting but pointing to your real Cosmos DB account on the [App Settings or Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings).

Comment: Thank you. For your last line comment: I have a `local.settings.json` and `settings.json`. Current both have same configs. Once change configs in local.settings and I tested using emulator and later I simply deploy the function, it will use the config in `settings.json` and not `local.setings.json`, right?

Comment: Correct, by default, the Azure Functions templates do not deploy the `local.settings.json` file when you deploy, so that file does not exist in the deployed bits. For connection strings you normally don't need to have a `settings.json` file, you can rely on the configuration of the Function App as the last link in the response points to.

Comment: Hi, I have another question. I have changed my connection string to point to cosmos emulator. Now when I run my (modified) azure function (not yet deployed), will the blob triggers run deployed (i.e. old) function or on the (new but not deployed) modified function. I want the latter. Basically I justt want to test my new function with blob triggers and see results on cosmos emulator.

Comment: @Sulphur - please refrain from asking follow-up questions in comments under an answer; you should post a new question. Otherwise, this just becomes a discussion-in-comments (and that is not what comments are for).